Getting failed to parse YAML inputs "while scanning plain scalar, found a comment between adjacent scalars"
I'm trying to deploy an Azure accelerator with two input files. When I run the deploy-accelerator I get the following error

Write-Error:
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\ALZ\4.1.0\Public\New-ALZEnvironment.ps1:177:28
… putConfig = Get-ALZConfig -configFilePath $inputConfigFilePath
-input …
|                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Failed to parse YAML inputs. Please check the YAML file for errors and try again. Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s):
 | "While scanning plain scalar, found a comment between adjacent scalars."

Exception:
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\ALZ\4.1.0\Private\Config-Helpers\Get-ALZConfig.ps1:31:13

input below
---
iac_type: terraform
bootstrap_module_name: alz_azuredevops
starter_module_name: complete_multi_region
bootstrap_location: eastus
starter_locations:
  - eastus
  - westus
root_parent_management_group_id:  
subscription_id_management:  
subscription_id_identity:  
subscription_id_connectivity:  
azure_devops_personal_access_token:  
azure_devops_agents_personal_access_token: ""
azure_devops_organization_name:  
use_separate_repository_for_templates: true
bootstrap_subscription_id:  
service_name: alz
environment_name: mgmt
postfix_number: 1
azure_devops_use_organisation_legacy_url: false
azure_devops_create_project: true
azure_devops_project_name:  
use_self_hosted_agents: true
use_private_networking: true
allow_storage_access_from_my_ip: false
apply_approvers:
  - johndoe@nowhere.com
create_branch_policies: true
bootstrap_module_version: latest
starter_module_version: latest
output_folder_path: /accelerator/output
type here

I've run the inputs through yaml lint and it verifies as valid yaml. I also took out all the comments and tried to run the deployment again and still get the same error. I'm stuck, any ideas?
